# Last two items in list of numbers not swapping

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

So the problem I am having is that I have coded a quicksort algorithm and it does work. It consistently sorts all the numbers from least to greatest. However, there is always two items that should be swapped at the very end and I am not sure where to implement the swap. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void swap(double* a, double* b) {
    double temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(double arr[], int start, int end) {
    double pivot = arr[end];
    int pivotIndex = start;
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < end; index++) {
        if (arr[index] < pivot) {
            swap(arr[index], arr[pivotIndex]);
            pivotIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[index]);
    return index;
}

void quickSort(double arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int part = partition(arr, start, end);
        quickSort(arr, start, part - 1);
        quickSort(arr, part + 1, end);
    }
}


void main() {
    double numList[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < size(numList); i++) {
        numList[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << setw(2) << left << numList[i] << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    quickSort(numList, 0, size(numList) - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size(numList); i++) {
        cout << setw(2) << left << numList[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

The list should sort with that code but the last two items aren't swapping.

Comment: Just use `std::sort`.

Comment: `std::swap` exists.

Comment: Rename your function `myswap` and try again.

Comment: Why does `partition` look at elements starting from `0`, and not from `start`? I'm pretty sure you can have `pivotIndex` run off the end of the array, and trigger undefined behavior by way of access out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the Lomuto partition scheme, but you did not properly transcribe partition() correctly.

```
int partition(double arr[], int start, int end) {
    double pivot = arr[end];
    int pivotIndex = start;
    int index;

 // Mistake 1: Start at the first element of the partition, not 0! 
 // for (index = 0; index < end; index++) {
    for (index = start; index < end; index++) {
        if (arr[index] < pivot) {
            swap(arr[index], arr[pivotIndex]);
            pivotIndex++;
        }
    }

 // Mistake 2: Swap the last element of the partition.
 // swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[index]);
    swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[end]);

//  Mistake 3: return the pivot index.
//  return index;
    return pivotIndex;
}
```